# Can the text of an Android TextView be set outside of the onCreate() method?

Tags: java, android, onesignal

I'm trying to set the text of a TextView in my Android app using the following function:

```java
@Override
public void onOSSubscriptionChanged(OSSubscriptionStateChanges stateChanges) {
    if (!stateChanges.getFrom().getSubscribed() && stateChanges.getTo().getSubscribed()) {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setMessage("You have successfully subscribed to push notifications!")
                .show();
        // Get player ID and output to Main Activity
        TextView playerIdView = findViewById(R.id.playerIdView);
        playerIdView.setText(stateChanges.getTo().getUserId());
    }

    Log.i("Debug", "onOSPermissionsChanged: " + stateChanges);
}
```

This uses the [OneSignal API](https://onesignal.com) to get the user's unique ID, which is returned as a string. After some debugging I realised the contents of a `TextView` can't be changed outside of the `onCreate()` method. However, the `stateChanges` parameter is required, which only exists within `onOSSubscriptionChanged`. Is there any way of getting around this?

EDIT: the error was elsewhere. `stateChanges.getTo().getUserId()` was returning `null`.

Comment: Try using textview inside runonUIthread . If it didnt work share logs

Comment: it sure can, recommend to go through activity life cycle.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set it on UI thread

```
playerIdView.post(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
       playerIdView.setText(stateChanges.getTo().getUserId());
    } 
});
```

**or**

```
Handler mainHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

Runnable myRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override 
    public void run() {
       playerIdView.setText(stateChanges.getTo().getUserId());} 
    };
mainHandler.post(myRunnable);
```

Comment: And you need to call `findViewById()` from inside a class that extends Activity (or any class that has a `findViewById()`)

Comment: @Ali if `onOSSubscriptionChanged` contains in activity class, then not.

Comment: @Bravewave what do you facing with when try it?

Comment: @AntonA. pardon?

Comment: the error was elsewhere. `stateChanges.getTo().getUserId()` was returning `null`

Answer (score 1):

you need to initialize you `textview` in your `onCreateView()` method and after that you can use that `textView` pretty much anywhere as long as you are in UI thread. So change your code to below:

Declare your `textview` globally so that you can use it anywhere in your activity instance.

```
TextView playerIdView;

 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

  playerIdView = findViewById(R.id.playerIdView);   

}
```

and then in your `onSSubscription` method just do the following:

```
 @Override
public void onOSSubscriptionChanged(OSSubscriptionStateChanges stateChanges) {
    if (!stateChanges.getFrom().getSubscribed() && stateChanges.getTo().getSubscribed()) {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setMessage("You have successfully subscribed to push notifications!")
                .show();
        // Get player ID and output to Main Activity
        playerIdView.setText(stateChanges.getTo().getUserId());
    }

    Log.i("Debug", "onOSPermissionsChanged: " + stateChanges);
}
```

Comment: The text still isn't being updated. `TextView` delcared globally

Comment: the error was elsewhere. `stateChanges.getTo().getUserId()` was returning `null`

Comment: @Bravewave then the problem is not with your textview rather `getUserId()`

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
        @override
        public void run() {
            playerIdView.setText(stateChanges.getTo().getUserId());
        }
    })
```